# How to convert python list of points to numpy image array?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a python list of points (x/y coordinates):

```
   [(200, 245), (344, 248), (125, 34), ...]
```

It represents a contour on a 2d plane. I would like to use some numpy/scipy algorithms for smoothing, interpolation etc. They normally require numpy array as input. For example [`scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom.html).

What is the simplest way to get the right numpy array from my list of points?

**EDIT:** I added the word "image" to my question, hope it is clear now, I am really sorry, if it was somehow misleading. Example of what I meant (points to binary image array).

Input:

```
[(0, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1]]
```

Rounding the accepted answer here is the **working sample**:

```
import numpy as np

coordinates = [(0, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1)]

x, y = [i[0] for i in coordinates], [i[1] for i in coordinates]
max_x, max_y = max(x), max(y)

image = np.zeros((max_y + 1, max_x + 1))

for i in range(len(coordinates)):
    image[max_y - y[i], x[i]] = 1
```

Comment: `numpy.array(your_list)` is probably a good start...?

Comment: not much of a start... but really what means represent anyways...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ah, better now, so you do have all the points you want to fill... then its very simple:

```
image = np.zeros((max_x, max_y))
image[coordinates] = 1
```

You could create an array first, but its not necessary.

Comment: @Alex, well you probably had to know that zoom work on images... Btw. forgot to set the datatype (`np.zeros((max_x, max_y), dtype=bool)`), though if you want to zoom, maybe no point.

Answer (score 0):

```
numpy.array(your_list)
```

numpy has very extensive documentation that you should try reading. You can find it online or by typing `help(obj_you_want_help_with)` (eg. `help(numpy)`) on the REPL.

Comment: I am sorry but how can this help me? I said that I need a numpy array that I can use as input for scipy functions and gave an example (zoom).

Answer (score 0):

Building on what Jon Clements and Dunes said, after doing

```
new_array = numpy.array([(200, 245), (344, 248), (125, 34), ...])
```

you will get a two-dimensional array where the first column contains the x coordinates and the second column contains the y coordinates. The array can be further split into separate x and y arrays like this:

```
x_coords = new_array[:,0]
y_coords = new_array[:,1]
```

Comment: ... or directly as `(x_coords, y_coords)=new_array.T` where `.T` is a shortcut to the `.transpose()` method.

Comment: Rigt, Pierre GM. I almost mentioned that since it's my preferred way as it uses fewer commands. I decided what I wrote was maybe simpler from a conceptual standpoint. The more examples the merrier, though.