# Python - interpolate data points into numpy image

Tags: python, numpy

Given a list of irregularly spaced data points that are used to describe a line or curve or some noisy function, I would like to convert the data to an image-like numpy array, where each "pixel" either contains data or not (say, 1/0 for data / no data).  A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670736/how-to-convert-python-list-of-points-to-numpy-image-array); however, I do not necessarily have a data point for each possible x position, and my points are not necessarily integer values.

For example, say I wanted my output image array to span `-10 <= x <= 30`, `0 <= y <= 20` with each element in the array spanning 1 distance unit (image array would be 20x40).  I have data points [(0.1, 0), (20, 5), (23.5, 18)] that I want to "plot".  I would like to find all elements in the array that fall on the line segments created by connecting these points, and populate the array by setting these elements equal to 1 and the rest equal to 0.

EDIT:  [This](http://www.icare.univ-lille1.fr/wiki/index.php/How_to_convert_a_matplotlib_figure_to_a_numpy_array_or_a_PIL_image) is a start, but it seems to convert an entire plot into an image, not just the data (so, it  includes axes, labels, etc).

Comment: You can calculate the lines from each of these points to the following point, but these lines are rarely going to be integer coordinates, like you said. If you wanted to you could probably include a threshold and if a set of integer coordinates are within that threshold from the lines then "activate" that coordinate. This will create a line-ish in the array, but won't be the most accurate.You could also simply treat each coordinate as a box (e.g. 0,0 is the box from [0->.99,0->.99], etc) and if the line goes through that box then activate it.

Comment: You can use the [Bresenham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) line drawing algorithm. Or just use a graphics library like PIL to draw your lines.

Comment: OTOH, if your points as supposed to be on a curve then you could join them with [Bézier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve).

Comment: @PM2Ring Do you know of a particular function in PIL (or another library) that handles this, or is there an easy way to use one of those libraries to accomplish this?  And no, I'm not necessarily assuming that the points lie on a smooth curve.

Comment: I guess should have specified that the points do not necessarily describe a smooth function.  I updated my first sentence to reflect that.

Comment: See https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.line